# CSS: Full width flex column doesn't stack on top of each other on webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

I have two divs in a container like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div-a"> Hello </div>
    <div class="div-b"> Lorem </div>
</div>
```

And I have set the container to `display:flex` and `flex-direction` to `column`.

I aim to align the 2 divs **on top of each other**. This works fine on Firefox but not on WebKit (Chrome/Safari). On WebKit, the columns align next to each other instead.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnxjL4tc/) so you can see.

My CSS is:

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box; 
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex; 
}

.div-a {
    background:lightgreen;
    order:2;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

.div-b {
    background:lightblue;
    order:1;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Why is this not working on WebKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get **`flex`** to work across browsers (especially Safari desktop and iOS ), you need to prefix all the related properties. Visit [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for browser support details.

**Example of `flex-direction: column;`**

```css
.container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.a {
    background: lightgreen;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.b {
    background: lightblue;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

**Example of `flex-direction: row;`**

```css
.container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.a, .b {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
.a {
    background: lightgreen;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.b {
    background: lightblue;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```